# Opening URL to facebook page wall does not work in UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I am trying to display my facebook page wall (a link of the form http://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME?sk=wall) by passing this as a request to UIWebView. The view opens with the generic page (http://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME) unless I login to facebook inside my app UIWebView.
The same link works fine in Safari even if I am not logged in.
How can I make the UIWebView show the wall page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook redirects Facebook pages differently on the mobile device over the computer web browser.

You'll have to use 'v' value parameter, but just to warn you, Facebook can change this parameter redirection at any time and therefore resulting in screwing up your FB wall link.

ex) http://m.facebook.com/WescomCreditUnion?v=wall

Comment: This seems to be a better link (mobile site + v parameter rather than the regular site with the sk parameter).

Comment: I tried that it works great in safari but not in `UIWebview`.http://stackoverflow.com/q/12621697/751026