# Not able to load facebook fan page wall in UIWebview

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-page, facebook-wall

In my app, I am trying to display Facebook fan page wall (eg.https://m.facebook.com/DonaldDuck) in the UIWebView. But white screen gets displayed and getting error as:

**Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “m.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."**

I have found the same issue as [stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621697/ipad-cannot-load-facebook-page-wall-in-uiwebview).

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374601/opening-url-to-facebook-page-wall-does-not-work-in-uiwebview?lq=1).

Also tried below links to display Facebook fan page wall.

```
http://m.facebook.com/DonaldDuck?v=wall
http://m.facebook.com/DonaldDuck?v=feed
```

**Code:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:FACEBOOK_LINK];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[requestObj setValue:@" Safari/537.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"]; // Line 1
[fbWebView setDelegate:self];
[fbWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

**Above Line 1, If I use then I am able to see wall page.But this is private api and i have to submit this app on apple store. So, i guess this will not work. :(**

Any idea how to resolve this issue on iPad? (It works with iPhone UIWebView)

Comment: take a look:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347410/iphone-secure-restfull-server-the-certificate-for-this-server-is-invalid

Comment: Hi,Nitin. Thanks for answering. I already found this solution but it will helpful for developing purpose. If I use this allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost method and submit it on apple store then apple will reject my app because this is a private api.